# how to hover a single line of a grid of divs

Tags: jquery, css, user-interface, grid, hover

I made a grid in css and js

the problem is that I want to hover a single line, but it takes the whole grid

I would like to hover on touch with the mouse: or vertical lines, or horizontal lines, or both if the mouse touch them

if I use `.grid:hover div` it takes the whole grid

if I use `.grid:hover` it takes only the bounding box of the grid

how can I do??

I think the better way could be by jquery but I don't know how to append this function to the grid

JS:

```
//DOOM 3 UI Grid
$( document ).ready(function() {
  //prepare grid size
  function createGrid(size) {
    var ratioW = Math.floor($( document ).width()/size),
        ratioH = Math.floor($( document ).height()/size);
  //prepare container
    var parent = $('<div />', {
        class: 'grid',
        width: ratioW  * size,
        height: ratioH  * size
    }).addClass('grid').appendTo('html');
  //loop single lines
    for (var i = 0; i < ratioH; i++) {
        for(var p = 0; p < ratioW; p++){
            $('<div />', {
                width: size - 1,
                height: size - 1
            }).appendTo(parent);
        }
    }
  }
  //create grid
  createGrid(50);
});
```

CSS

```
/* grid */
.grid {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,255,255,0.2);
  border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
.grid div {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,255,255,0.2);
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  float: left;
  z-index: 0;
}
.grid:hover div {
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is only for visual purpose and about to highlight the whole column and the whole row where belongs the div, then CSS and pseudos can help here

```js
//DOOM 3 UI Grid
$( document ).ready(function() {
  //prepare grid size
  function createGrid(size) {
    var ratioW = Math.floor($( document ).width()/size),
        ratioH = Math.floor($( document ).height()/size);
  //prepare container
    var parent = $('<div />', {
        class: 'grid',
        width: ratioW  * size,
        height: ratioH  * size
    }).addClass('grid').appendTo('html');
  //loop single lines
    for (var i = 0; i < ratioH; i++) {
        for(var p = 0; p < ratioW; p++){
            $('<div />', {
                width: size - 1,
                height: size - 1
            }).appendTo(parent);
        }
    }
  }
  //create grid
  createGrid(50);
});
```

```css
/* grid */
.grid {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,255,255,0.2);
  border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.grid div {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,255,255,0.2);
  border-width: 0 1px 1px 0;
  float: left;
  z-index: 0;
  position:relative;
}

.grid div:before,
.grid div:after {
  content:'';
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
  position:absolute;
  border:1px solid red;
  pointer-events:none;
  display:none;
}
.grid div:before {
  top:-1px;
  bottom:-1px;
  width:200vw;
  left:-100vw;
}
.grid div:after {
  left:-1px;
  right:-1px;
  height:200vw;
  top:-100vw;
}
.grid div:hover:before,
.grid div:hover:after {
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to make the borders of a single grid box red on hover?

```
.grid div:hover {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/afb8s8hL/) as example: